How to make a Electrical Diagram Steinmetz Circuit Delta 3 phase motor
I am now doing an internship and one of my task is to research if we can save costs on the ovens they are now producing. They want to reduce the components on the groundbase. I have found a solution of a apply a Steinmetz circuit. I have tested this and it worked all right.
The question I have right now is, at my Diagram I have the motor in star, but this is the normal condition not with the steinmetz, I want to add the steinmetz circuit to my motor in the diagram but I don't know how to do it, I want to have my motor in delta with the Steinmetz, I know all the wiring how to connect the circuit but I don't know how to put that down in a good and efficient way in my diagram. This is the system that I have right now.  Check picture one with the star diagram

and the 2nd picture is all the wiring of my Steinmetz circuit with a capacitor, All the calculations are all right but I don't know how to turn these wiring delta sheet to a electrical diagram. I hope someone has experience in creating diagram with delta. Online I only see diagrams of Star-Delta, but I just need a diagram of Delta with Steinmetz. Probably I am thinking way to difficult but I can't make it work right now. thanks in advance.

All the coils are black and the wiring colour I have added in red. I hope it is understandable. If I need to wire it, it is no problem but to create a diagram I don't have any idea.
Luc

also asked four minutes earlier at https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/how-to-make-a-electrical-diagram-steinmetz-circuit-delta-3-phase-motor.200334/

(In the diagram, the label with the non-live line looks a u much more than an N, possibly due to being mirrored (И?!).)

bert doorn - Hi, Where did those diagrams come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. "Datasheet XYZ" & URL). If the original source was a book or other offline material, please [edit] the question & add a full citation e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. (see the linked rule for details). See the [tour] & [help] for rules. TY

It is made by the company I am working for as an intern. I have the rights to use it.

@bertdoorn - Re: "It is made by the company I am working for as an intern. I have the rights to use it." So please add a suitable statement like that, next to each image for which it applies. It's not enough for you to have permission from them, you still need to provide a best-efforts reference here, please. TY
